# Custom Iterator returns Object

Tags: java, generics, iterator, iterable

I wrote a custom iterator for the class `MyList` this is what it looks like:

```
private class MyListIterator implements Iterator<ListItem> {
        // Constructor
        public MyListIterator() {
            nextElement = head;
        }

        @Override
        public ListItem next() {
        ...

    }
```

Then in the class `MyList` i create a new `MyListIterator` like this:

```
@Override
    public Iterator<ListItem> iterator() {
        MyListIterator iterator = new MyListIterator();
        return iterator;
    }
```

and finally i try to iterate over a `MyList` Object expecting `ListItem`s:

```
MyList list = new MyList();
for (ListItem item : list ) {
       System.out.println(item.value);
}
```

But i get the incompatible types error because the iterator returns `Object` types instead of `ListItem`. How do i fix it?

Edit: `MyList` implements `MyListInterface`:

```
public interface MyListInterface<T extends Comparable<T>> extends Iterable<T> {
    public Iterator<T> iterator();
}
```

But I'm not allowed to change anything in `MyListInterface`

```
private class ListItem {
        Comparable value;
        ListItem previous;
        ListItem next;

        public ListItem(Comparable value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: what about `list.iterator()` ?

Comment: Does `MyList` implement `Iterable` or `Iterable<ListItem>`?

Answer (score 0):

Your `MyList` class `implements Iterable` instead of `implements Iterable<ListItem>`. The compiler is providing a warning to you about this; pay attention to warnings.

With your update, you should use `implements MyListInterface<ListItem>`. You are in fact getting the warning I mentioned (use of raw type `MyListInterface`)--these warnings are intended to help you avoid and resolve problems like this.

Comment: MyList is implementing another interface which extends Iterable<T>. I'm not allowed to change anything in the interface, how do i make it work?

Comment: @LuccaBaumgärtner Can you show that part of the code as well? We need a [mcve].

Comment: In the exercise it says that ```ListItem``` should by a subclass of MyList with private access, so i can't use it as type when implementing ```MyListInterface```. I added ```ListItem``` to the question. Is there a way to make this work by using a generic type when implementing ```MyListInterface```

Comment: You have _another_ raw type that is giving you a warning. Perhaps you should have `class ListItem<T> { T value; }` and `MyList<T extends Comparable<T>> implements MyListInterface<T>`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you have mistakenly wrote that `MyList implements MyListInterface {`, forgetting to add the generic argument. This means that you are using a raw type, and you should ***not*** do this. See [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

The raw type `MyListInterface` has the super-interface of the raw type `Iterator`. Once you used one raw type, all the related types become raw (learn more about this in the [JLS section 4.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8)), so currently your `MyList` implements the non-generic `Iterable`, which returns a non generic `Iterator`, whose next method returns `Object`s. To make `MyList` implement `Iterable<ListItem>`, you need to write

```
class MyList implement MyListIterator<ListItem> {
```

If your `ListItem` is not `Comparable<ListItem>` yet, implement that as well.